# Evaluating sign of inequality under constraint

Tags: inequality

Suppose for real numbers $b$ and $c$ $$|b+c|-|b|<0.$$

Can I infer for any real $a$ that

$$|a+b+c|-|a+b|<0?$$

And if so, how should I formally derive this?

**Edit**: Additional question after comments, for which range of $a$ does the inequality hold?

Comment: for some real $a$? Try $a=0$ :-). Do you mean for *any* real $a$?

Comment: @gt6989b OK, I mean 'any'.

Answer (score 1):

for some real $a$? Try $a=0$ :-).

Do you mean for *any* real $a$? That's unlikely, pick $a = -b$ to guarantee $|a+b+c|-|a+b| = |c| \geq 0$.

Comment: OK thank you, that helps!

Comment: @tomka What is more interesting is to find the entire range of values of $a$ where it is true and false...

Comment: Yes, I just thought so too. I will edit the question to include this.